# How to show toast after performing some functionality in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I want to show something like toast after some functionality performed. i-e I have a save button and I want that when it pressed then a toast should be shown with the text Record Saved etc. I read posts that show toasts are only for back-ground agents. I know someone will give me good guidance. please specify some code.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Toast Prompt from the Coding4Fun Toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Toast%20Prompt) to perform a toast notification via code. After referencing the toolkit (ideally via NuGet) you can use it like this:

```
ToastPrompt toast = new ToastPrompt();
toast.Title = "Your app title";
toast.Message = "Record saved.";
toast.TextOrientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
toast.MillisecondsUntilHidden = 2000;
toast.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ApplicationIcon.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

toast.Show();
```

Answer (score 5):

I prefer `ProgressIndicator` in my apps but you can use `Popup` or [ToastPrompt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20348913/1136101).

Sample [project](http://sdrv.ms/Iq0z1u).

```
// popup member
private Popup popup;

// creates popup
private Popup CreatePopup()
{
    // text
    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
    tb.Foreground = (Brush)this.Resources["PhoneForegroundBrush"];
    tb.FontSize = (double)this.Resources["PhoneFontSizeMedium"];
    tb.Margin = new Thickness(24, 32, 24, 12);
    tb.Text = "Custom toast message";

    // grid wrapper
    Grid grid = new Grid();
    grid.Background = (Brush)this.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"];
    grid.Children.Add(tb);
    grid.Width = this.ActualWidth;

    // popup
    Popup popup = new Popup();
    popup.Child = grid;

    return popup;
}

// hides popup
private void HidePopup()
{
    SystemTray.BackgroundColor = (Color)this.Resources["PhoneBackgroundColor"];
    this.popup.IsOpen = false;
}

// shows popup
private void ShowPopup()
{
    SystemTray.BackgroundColor = (Color)this.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"];

    if (this.popup == null)
    {
        this.popup = this.CreatePopup();
    }

    this.popup.IsOpen = true;
}

// shows and hides popup with a delay
private async void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.ShowPopup();

    await Task.Delay(2000);

    this.HidePopup();
}
```

[image: Custom toast message]

Answer (score 1):

```
 using Windows.UI.Notifications;

 var toastXmlContent = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText02);

 var txtNodes = toastXmlContent.GetElementsByTagName("text");
 txtNodes[0].AppendChild(toastXmlContent.CreateTextNode("First Line"));
 txtNodes[1].AppendChild(toastXmlContent.CreateTextNode("Second Line" ));

 var toast = new ToastNotification(toastXmlContent);
 var toastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
 toastNotifier.Show(toast);
```

Comment: This doesn't need an external library and works just fine.